# facebook share button on javascript reloaded page

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, share

I have problem with facebook share button. I need to display it on page, which content is loaded with javascript. I have php template for this page when I included

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/cs_CZ/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=518870138182144";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); 
</script>
```

and

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];/*."?      openGalleryDetail=".$detaili18n->getId(); */?>" data-type="button_count"></div>
```

When I add facebook script and facebook-root div on default layout it is not working on this javascript part of page.

Now it works fine when first javacsript content shows, whenever I try to change it facebook share button is not shown. How can I repair it to work always (also when javacsript content is changed)?

Can be seen on this page: http://www.brilance.cz/cs/snubni-prsteny-17

Answer (score 0):

The href for all of the share buttons is the same, so if you left the code in and used the javascript to only overwrite the other content, probably by putting it inside another div, you would avoid the issue. However, if you need to be able to change the share button, you may have to unload the facebook script and reload it (that is, the script in the head of your code). What is most likely happening is that the facebook code only runs once, upon load, so if you replace the button it doesn't rerun the script.